# Make a listview of buttons that switch to different screens in kivy

Tags: python, button, screen, kivy, listitem

I've another problem in my project with kivy.
I have 50 screens and I want to first display a list of buttons that refers to the screens When a button is pressed, the screenmanager should switch to the relevant screen. Here is my code but I don't know what should I do!

source:
https://gist.github.com/daryasary/3a2be816c1f35b748866

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
#from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
#from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Builder.load_string('''
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
            text: 'Credit'
            #on_press:root.show_popup()
        #ListView:
            #size_hint: .8,.9
            #adapter:
                #sla.SimpleListAdapter(
                #data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
                #cls=button.Button
                #selection_mode='single',
                #allow_empty_selection=False)
        ListView:
            size_hint: .8, .97
            item_strings: [str(index) for index in range(50)]

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
            text: 'atlas'


<Page>:
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:(.1, None)
        Button:
        text: 'MENU'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
        text:'Title'
        size_hint:(1, .2)
    Image:
        source: '/home/hosein/Pictures/1.png'
        size_hint:(1, .8)
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:(.1, None)
        Button:
        text: 'atlas'
''')



class MenuPage(Screen):
    M = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')

    def plays(self):
        if MenuPage.M.state == 'stop':
        MenuPage.M.play()
    else:
        MenuPage.M.stop()



class Page(Screen):
    pass



sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)
for i in range(50):
    name = Page(name=str(i))
    sm.add_widget(name)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
    return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: i want to make selectable view with 49 buttons, on press each item(button) the screen switchmanager to refers screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 50 "Pages" are all identical so it would make more sense to replace them all with a single page that changes the picture/sound content depending on the selected menu button. It uses less resources and will be easier to debug and maintain.

Your resource files (e.g. 1.png) would also be better organised either by grouping them in a fixed subdirectory or referring to them in code using the indirect mechanism provided by the libraries ([link](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.resources.html?highlight=resource))

Regarding your question; the listview mechanism allows a number of different approaches but simpleadapter won't suffice. There are plenty of good examples for lists provided in the ListView documentation ([link](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html?highlight=listview))

At minimum, you'll need a listadapter, a function to respond to the button presses, and the binding of the function to the button objects. You can do this by binding the `listadapter.on_selection_change` event handler but I find it neater to create a button item class with a specific handler so that's what I'm providing below.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty

Builder.load_string('''
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
#:import factory kivy.factory

<MenuButton>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(24)
    on_release: app.on_menu_selection(self.index)

<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'Credit'
                #on_press:root.show_popup()
        ListView:
            size_hint: .8,.9
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=app.data,
                cls=factory.Factory.MenuButton,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                args_converter=root.args_converter)

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'atlas'


<Page>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'MENU'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Button:
                text:'Title'
                size_hint:(1, .2)
            Image:
                source: '/home/hosein/Pictures/1.png'
                size_hint:(1, .8)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)

            Button:
                text: 'atlas'
''')

class MenuButton(ListItemButton):
    index = NumericProperty(0)

class MenuPage(Screen):
    M = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')

    def plays(self):
        if MenuPage.M.state == 'stop':
            MenuPage.M.play()
        else:
            MenuPage.M.stop()

    def args_converter(self, row_index, title):
        print ("{0}={1}".format(row_index, title))

        return {
            'index': row_index,
            'text': title
        }

class Page(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    data = ListProperty(["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(50)])

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
        sm.add_widget(menu)
        for i in range(50):
            name = Page(name=str(i))
            sm.add_widget(name)
        return sm

    def on_menu_selection(self, index):
        self.root.current = str(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Glad to help. But if it's really what you're looking for then please accept the answer

Comment: Its working but I want to change the background color of listview icon buttons from Green to white.

Comment: As of Kivy 1.11.0, ListView is deprecated in favor of the new MVC-based RecycleView, so the code in this answer now produces " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.listview'". For the solution to that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601384/kivy-unknown-class-listview-error-code/56601656#56601656